# SlikSVN + Windows 2008 Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Installed SlikSvn on Window 2008 server
Created Repository at c:\dia\svn\repos

running this windows service as:

sc create svn binpath= "\"c:\program files\sliksvn\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r c:\dia\svn\repos" displayname= "Subversion Server" depend= Tcpip start= auto

This works fine.

running svnserve as -d --listen-host xx.xx.xx.xx --list-host 3690

when try to browse repository as svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/dia/svn/repos getting error 
'No repository found in 'svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/dia/svn/repos'

but works fine when try to browse repo as file:///c:/dia/svn/repos.

What am i missing ... any help please ???

thanks

Comment: I could not get SlikSvn server running as a Windows Service for some reason.  I tried this question for guidance, as well as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729282/svnserve-giving-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-re?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVN repository is at C:\dia\svn\repos, but you're setting up the server root to be C:\dialog?

[Edit: OK, so that's fixed...]

Let's take a look at this then:

You're passing this as the *repository root*:
c:\dia\svn\repos

But then you try to *connect to*:
svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/dia/svn/repos

Now, since your *repository root* is what you expose as the *root of your svn server* and whatever you request for is appended to that, you're now actually requesting for c:\dia\svn\repos\dia\svn\repos

Instead, you probably want to try just this:
svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/

Comment: My mistake: yes was set to c:\dia\svn\repos

Answer (score 2):

When the repos is in

```
c:\dia\svn\repos
```

You need to pass the root that contains your repository/repositories, not the path to a single repository (because then you would have to run a new service instance for every repository).

This means you should use:

```
-r c:\dia\svn
```

as argument

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that SlickSvn (hopefully) isn't exposing your root filesystem. Try to connect to svn://xx.xx.xx.xx:3690 and see if you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is repos the name of a single repository or the parent path for all your current/future SVN repositories?

If repos is indeed the actual repository you are trying to reach, then you will first need to configure the service to point to the parent/root path (as mentioned by Sander...) and then, you need to restart the service. Once done, try accessing the repository like this:

svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/repos

But if "repos" is already the root of the repository(ies) then the service config is fine - you just need to try accessing via svn://*servername*/*repository_name*  - there is no need to provide the parent path name here.