# SVNserve giving Error 1053 The service did not respond to the start or control request

Tags: svn, windows-services

I have installed SlikSVN and I'm trying to set up svnserve. SlikSvn is installed in C:\Program Files\SlikSvn and C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin is in the path.

The registry entry for the service is currently"

```
svnserve.exe --service -r "C:\SVNReposities" DisplayName= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

However, when I try and start the service I get the following error:

> Could not start SVNService service on Local Computer
>   Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

If I change the registry entry to"

```
svnserve.exe --service -r "C:\SVNReposities"
```

The service starts correctly. I can't figure out what is wrong with the second half of the statement, does anyone know what is wrong or have any resources that could help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it working

The solutions was to deleted the service I already created, and then followed the following instructions on tortise svn website.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html

I created the service with the following command
sc create svnserve binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service --root C:\SVNReposities" displayname= "Subversion" depend= tcpip start= auto

and the resulting registry entry was
"C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svnserve.exe" --service --root C:\SVNReposities

I believe the problem was I didn't escape the double quotes correctly when creating the service. This caused the register entries to be created incorrectly and the DisplayName, depend and start were left on the end of the ImagePath Registry entry.

The end result was when SVN Serve started, it consumed the the entire line as the root directory which couldn't be found causing the service to not start.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things about your answer:

1. Jeff Atwood used "-r" and you used "--root".  I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not
2. The other difference is that you added a "\ in front of "C:\Program Files.....  According to Subversion docs that does make a difference. (see below)

> sc create svnserve binpath= "c:\svnserve\svnserve.exe --service --root c:\repos" displayname= "Subversion" depend= tcpip start= auto
>
> If any of the paths include spaces, you have to use (escaped) quotes around the path, like this:
>
> sc create svnserve binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service --root c:\repos" displayname= "Subversion" depend= tcpip start= auto